# Как осуществить верстку так чтобы не было масштабирования на iPhone?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

При нажатии на кнопку несколько раз масштабируется экран

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Мальчик или девочка?</title>
</head>
<body>
  <footer>
    <h1>Мальчик или девочка?</h1>
  </footer>
  <main>
    <div id="blockLeft" class="female">
      <div id="femaleWin"></div>
      <h3>Девочка</h3>
      <button id="femaleButton" onclick="incrementClickFemale()"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="blockRight" class="male">
      <div id="maleWin"></div>
      <h3>Мальчик</h3>
      <button id="maleButton" onclick="incrementClickMale()"></button>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

````
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, pink 50%, skyblue 50%);
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}

#blockLeft {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    left: 18%;
}
#blockRight {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    left: 68%;

}

#maleWin {
    margin-left: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}

#femaleWin {
    margin-left: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}

#maleButton {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#femaleButton {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 90px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    main {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
    #blockLeft, #blockRight {
        position: static;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to top, pink 50%, skyblue 50%) no-repeat;
        display: inline-flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #blockRight {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #maleWin, #femaleWin {
        margin-left: 25px;
        width: 30px;
        position: static;
    }

    #maleButton, #femaleButton {
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    
    h3 {
    
        font-size: 30px;
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Самый легкий способ отключения этой функции - это использование HTML тега . Атрибут user-scalable позволяет увеличить или уменьшить масштаб на мобильном устройстве. Чтобы отключить функцию масштабирования, необходимо задать значение “no” для этого атрибута.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```